# img src not working in Vue js and must have a correct path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router

image src not working.
can anybody help me?

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in businessItems" :key="index" class="business-item">
    <div class="item-wrap">
        <div class="wishlist">
            <i class="icon-wishlist-line"></i>
            <i class="icon-wishlist d-none"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img :src="require(`@/assets/images/business/${item.img_url}`)">
        </div>
        <h2 class="title">{{item.title}}</h2>

        <StarRating :rate="item.rate" />

    </div>
</div>
```

img src is bind with require from node.js but unfortunately is not working

Comment: Please show what the file structure looks like to understand what you're trying to reference?

Comment: It should work. Check out the path is correct. Otherwise give us more info.

Answer (score 0):

How about use `public` path or path, I mean remove `require`

```
<img :src=`/assets/images/business/${item.img_url}`/>
```

And way i see it you can assert / for end tag

Comment: unfortunately not working. require translate @ to main path

Comment: that give an error ------
Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value

Answer (score 0):

This code has not been tested but I'm sure it should do the trick. The most important is the `getImg` method which allows you to access `require()` and get the image path.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in businessItems" :key="index" class="business-item">
      <div class="item-wrap">
        <div class="wishlist">
          <i class="icon-wishlist-line"></i>
          <i class="icon-wishlist d-none"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img :src="getImg(item.img_url)">
        </div>
        <h2 class="title">{{item.title}}</h2>   
        <StarRating :rate="item.rate" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import businessItems from '@/services/business';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      businessItems,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getImg(url) {
      return require(`@/assets/images/business/${url}`);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```